# Guava Futures.transform with "Real" Executor vs. transformAsync with DirectExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, guava

Say I have two heavyweight IO blocking operations, findMatchInSomeDB() and getDetailsFromOtherDB(String objectKey). Furthermore, I want them to run in the background, and use Guava Futures to chain them together because one depends on the result of the other *(I know this could just be done sequentially in a simple Callable, but keeping it simple for illustration purposes)*:

Is there any practical or nuanced difference between the `consumeChain` and `consumeChainAsync` methods below?

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;

public class Consumer
{
   private final Retriever retriever;
   private final ListeningExecutorService executorSvc;

   public Consumer(Retriever retriever, ListeningExecutorService executorSvc)
   {
      this.retriever = retriever;
      this.executorSvc = executorSvc;
   }

   private void consumeChain(String searchCriteria) throws Exception
   {
      ListenableFuture<String> futureMatch = executorSvc.submit(
         () -> retriever.findMatchInSomeDB(searchCriteria));

      Function<String, DataObject> keyToDataObj = objectKey ->
         retriever.getDetailsFromOtherDB(objectKey);

      // using "real" executor service so transform function runs
      // in the background
      ListenableFuture<DataObject> futureDataObj = Futures.transform(
         futureMatch, keyToDataObj, executorSvc);

      // ...do some other stuff in this thread...

      // do something with futureDataObj result
      futureDataObj.get();
   }

   private void consumeChainAsync(String searchCriteria) throws Exception
   {
      ListenableFuture<String> futureMatch = executorSvc.submit(
         () -> retriever.findMatchInSomeDB(searchCriteria));

      AsyncFunction<String, DataObject> keyToDataObj = objectKey ->
      {
         return executorSvc.submit(
            () -> retriever.getDetailsFromOtherDB(objectKey));
      };

      // using DirectExecutor because the transform function
      // only creates and submits a Callable
      ListenableFuture<DataObject> futureDataObj = Futures.transformAsync(
         futureMatch, keyToDataObj, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());

      // ...do some other stuff in this thread...

      // do something with futureDataObj
      futureDataObj.get();
   }
}
```

As far as I can tell, both will run each heavyweight operation via `executorSvc`, and both will propagate cancellation and/or execution failure.

It seems that the only point of `transformAsync` (instead of just using `transform` with an executor other than DirectExecutor) is for when you're working with an API that returns ListenableFuture instead of directly running the operation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the only point of `transformAsync` (instead of just using `transform` with an executor other than DirectExecutor) is for when you're working with an API that returns ListenableFuture instead of directly running the operation.

I think that's the idea.

However, I can think of a small difference that makes `transformAsync` slightly better: If you call `cancel(true)` on the output `Future`, `transform` currently [won't interrupt the thread that runs `getDetailsFromOtherDB`](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1989). In contrast, `transformAsync` will (by calling `cancel(true)` on the `ListenableFuture` returned from the `ListeningExecutorService`). `transform` *should* propagate interruption, but there are some subtleties to getting this right, covered in the link above.